# Not sure if I should follow google sign-in documentation

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, google-signin, openid-connect

I am building a mobile app in react native with an asp.net core backend, and trying to integrate google sign-on.

In [this official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), google suggests to retrieve an `id_token` on the client side, and then send that `id_token` to the backend server (emphasis mine) to authorize:

> after a user successfully signs in, **send the user's ID token to your
>   server** using HTTPS. **Then, on the server, verify the integrity of
>   the ID token** and use the user information contained in the token to
>   establish a session or create a new account.

In this thread though, there are some pretty strong opinions that this way of using the id_token is incorrect, ie:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2015#issuecomment-262748581

> yes they [google] are doing it wrong. All specs and threat models are clear
>   on this. id_token is for the client, access token for the resource
>   server.

Can somebody suggest the right way to do this? I am not clear what the alternative is. Can I follow the google documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If your backend is also the client, it doesn't have to be wrong.

Two main questions to know if you could use the `id_token`:

- Is your backend the audience (which would probably mean that it holds the client id and secret)?
- Does your backend want to know the identity of the one **authenticated**, or is it mainly interested in the permissions of the one **authorized**?  (This comes down to who has the authoritative answer of which user has what authorization; the IdP or the client?)

In short, `id_token` proves authentication **to the audience**, not to anyone else.  `access_token` provides authorization.

Comment: thanks for the info. The steps I followed to get the token on the mobile client said to create **android** credentials in the google API credentials manager, which does not output a secret (as opposed to **web application** credentials). Ultimately all I want to do is 1. user logs into google in the front-end 2. front-end sends id_token to backend 2. backend verifies id_token is legit, analyzes claims about the user, and establishes a properly authorized session in my own application. That seems to be what the google documentation suggests to do, but additional details are seemingly lacking.

Answer (score 1):

As fiddur wrote, it's about audience (`aud` field) value of an ID token. If the mobile app and the backend share the client_id, then the ID token will be valid for both - the backend and the app.

If they don't share the client_id, both client_id-s should be included in the audience and the client_id of the mobile app should be in the authorized party (`azp`) field. But it can be tricky for issuing (multiple consents and such), see [this OpenID Connect issue](https://bitbucket.org/openid/connect/issues/973/).

For me, the confusing part of the Google documentation is the ID token validator, which should know client_id-s of all clients that access it and trust ID tokens issued to these clients without having backend's own client_id in the audience field:

```
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
    .build();
```

I think this is against OpenID Connect spec ([ID token validation](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation)):

> The Client MUST validate that the aud (audience) Claim contains its client_id value registered at the Issuer identified by the iss (issuer) Claim as an audience. The aud (audience) Claim MAY contain an array with more than one element. The ID Token MUST be rejected if the ID Token does not list the Client as a valid audience, or if it contains additional audiences not trusted by the Client.

But if you have a list of trusted clients, the Google way may be secure too.

Thinking about possible alternatives, using access tokens, we will run into the same issues, since you can get the audience from the [Introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2) (Google calls it `tokeninfo` endpoint) and you cannot create your own scopes using Google as an OAuth2 provider.

If you could have your own scope for the action of "signing in to that specific backend", that would be probably solve the issue - the access token would be issued to the mobile app (audience) and it would contain the scope specific for the backend (so the backend would trust it) and the authentication provider would present a consent describing the action the mobile wants to perform with the token.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So if, as per the google documentation, my UI gets an id_token and passes it to the backend, and then the backend validates the token using google's token verifier with the same client_id used by the front and back, and then establishes its own session by returning my own app's JWT token back to the frontend, does this correspond to one of the official OpenID Connect "flows"? I am struggling to map what google suggests to do with the various OpenID Connect tutorials and overviews.

Comment: No, that doesn't correspond with OAuth2 flows. The flows desribe how to get tokens, this is about using an ID token. With a website frontend and backend, you could just use the Auth code flow with the backend as a client. The frontend would not touch any token and it would just get your new session identifier. But with native apps, you cannot use it that way and the app must get the token first and then send it to the backend.

Comment: I see! So should I rather try to use one of the OAuth flows, or is this a valid usage of the id_token? I take it that the way google sign-in retrieves the token initially on the client side corresponds to a flow.

Comment: It's not an intended usage of ID tokens, but I would stick to it if Google recommends it. You could also use the Auth code flow with the backend as a client, so the backend gets the code (and then tokens from the `/token` endpoint) and then it would send a redirect (HTTP 30x) to a [Private-Use URI Scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-7) so the mobile app would get the backend's own JWT, but that would be like creating your own protocol and you would probably run into security issues (like what URI to use and trust).